# How to force an exception while debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am running my application in debug mode, and I would like to manually throw an exception (i.e. not from within the code). Is there any way to do this?

Of course, running `throw new Exception("My forced exception");` in the Command or Immediate window doesn't work.

EDIT: I want the exception to be caught by the try-catch statement that surrounds the code I'm debugging.

Comment: I've answered below but curious why you are trying to do this?

Comment: I had a desire to do this because I was in a complicated state (processing a large text file), and the catch that would have helped me figure out the error was actually further down the chain and the catch that I hit didn't have another "throw" in it

Answer (score 88, accepted):

One possible way is to break on a line and manually change a nullable variable in the code path to `null` just before an operation on it occurs. This will cause a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown.

Comment: +1. There are other similar "change state" actions (like change file name, change text to be non-parsable,...) that allow code itself to trigger exception. I don't think there is a way to add exception that would never be thrown by the code (also be interested to learn otherwise).

Comment: I think my answer is cleaner as you could call it from anywhere. Otherwise you have to keep adding code just before where you are interested in to throw an exception?

Comment: It also assumes that the subject code uses a reference variable that you can change.  What if the method uses all value variables?

Comment: Additionally, if the block you're in does not contain any variable, you _may_ be saved by moving the cursor elsewhere in the method (by dragging the arrow) to try to trigger an exception elsewhere. In my case, I had to move the next line being executed outside of my if block to trigger a null ref elsewhere.

Answer (score 13):

You could add a method similar to:

```
public static void ThrowAnException(string message)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(message);
}
```

Then, using the **Immediate** window, you could call `ThrowAnException("Whoops")`

Comment: Exceptions in the Immediate window don't pass back to the running code state, do they?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Yes, they do and will stop in the usual way. I have just double checked this by running my code in an example project.

Comment: I think this defeats the purpose. Adding this code just to be able to debug exceptions seems like a bad idea to me. I would rather modify state and trigger the exception that way.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:  Actually, I strongly agree with Belogix on this, modifying state manually on-the-fly seems both error-prone and very susceptible to unintended side-effects.  Plus, oft-times the state you want to modify is not readily accessible.  a public static method like this can just be thrown into a debugging utilities class/library and called from anywhere.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Fair enough. In either case I would prefer to cover this through unit tests rather than manual debugging.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Agreed.  For me, this is usually a debugging issue.

Comment: I agree re unit testing and I added a comment to the original question at same time as submitting my answer asking what was the intention of raising an exception.

Comment: While this does get an exception thrown, the exception can't be caught by the running code. I tried setting up an example where I call ThrowAnException() while the debugger is within an try-catch. The exception is thrown in the debugger, but it is not caught. I can continue running the code as if an exception never occurred.

Comment: Does not get caught by the code it just throws an exception in the debugger that does not affect the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running within the context of a unit test, and the point where you want the exception to originate is behind an injected interface or class, you can create a mock object that throws the exception.

The advantage of this is, once you're happy that you've replicated the error, you can construct a new unit test for your regression suite.

Answer (score -6):

Try to use the immediate window while you are on a break point.

Comment: I tried this first, but it does not work: "Invalid expression term 'throw'".

Comment: What about creating a function called ThrowMyException(). Then calling that function through the immediate window?

Comment: Please update your answer to include complete instructions on how you would use the immediate window to solve this problem.