# Still getting NullReferenceException even if I use try{}catch{}

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

I have the code below:

```cs
----
```

> System.NullReferenceException on line:
> downloadLinkList.Add(item.SelectSingleNode(".//a").Attributes["href"].Value);

How can I handle it properly and make it not crash anymore? I lived under the impression that it should have just skipped ahead.

Using `break` is not an option either as I still want the info of that certain page which didn't have the needed `href`.

Comment: Are you doing this from visual studio, while debigging your code? Then please see [How to force an exception while debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864077/how-to-force-an-exception-while-debugging-in-visual-studio) and [Manage exceptions with the debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Let me guess, your running in debug mode. Yes, then you will see all exceptions. If you press continue, it will be handled in the catch. Note: DON'T use exceptions for normal situation handling. They're called "exception" for a reason. If a null reference occurs commonly, implement null checking and conditional execution

Comment: `NullReferenceException != ArgumentNullException` although the cause is usually the same

Comment: @Charlieface my post was obviously not about that part of the code...

Comment: @JHBonarius yep, thank you a lot for your tip! And, indeed, I was running in debug mode and the Exception Settings were set such that it breaks whenever that exception occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Try/Catch` mechanism will not prevent the exception to happen. It will prevent it to propagate/bubble up.

```
 try
 {
    downloadLinkList.Add(item.SelectSingleNode(".//a").Attributes["href"].Value);
 }
 catch(NullReferenceException)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("NullReferenceException in TaskId: " + taskId);
 }
 Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Without the `try/catch` mechanism the "Hello" will never be printed because the exception interrupted the normal code flow. By catching the exception you are able to do something with the exception and the rest of the code can continue.

But it's possible your IDE break the execution to show you the exception (depending on your settings) but you can just click on "continue" (F5) and it will continue to your `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Yep. I just thought that, if implemented in a real-world scenario, it would pop up and just break. I just realized now that my Exception settings where set to "Break when this occurs", so probably that's why. My fault for not noticing that it still runs after pressing F5. Thank you, nonetheless!